# std::forward and copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I have started leaning C++ recently. And I have a question on std::forward with lvalue reference and rvalue reference.
In my understanding, The Func(mc) in the following code suppose to call
Func(T& t) because of template parameter deduction rule. And copy constructor of MyClass should be called inside the function with a message, "copy constructor". However I cannot get it when I run the program.
I checked that std::forwad with rvalue reference and copy constructor is working well in other lines.
 Please help me to understand what happen in the code. If I make easy mistake or misunderstanding, I am sorry for taking your time. Thank you very much.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { printf("constructor.\n"); };
    MyClass(MyClass&) { printf("copy constructor.\n"); };
    MyClass(const MyClass&) { printf("const copy constructor.\n"); };
    MyClass(MyClass&&) { printf("move constructor.\n"); };
    int val = 3;
};

template <typename T>
void Func(T&& t) {
    T new_t_(std::forward<T>(t));
    new_t_.val *= 2;
};

main() {
    MyClass mc;
    Func(mc);  // lvalue <- Func(T&)
    Func(MyClass());  // rsvalue <- Func(T&&)
    printf("mc.val=%d\n", mc.val); // this is for check

    MyClass mc2(mc);  // this is for check of copy constructor
}
```

Output when I run program is following,

```
constructor.
constructor.
move constructor.
mc.val=6
copy constructor.
```

I think it should have "copy constructor" between the first and the second "constructor" messages.

Thank you very much again.

Comment: A `MyClass(MyClass&)` constructor is not very useful for many classes. With the RAII pattern, one usually only follows the [Rule Of Five](http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/rule-of-five.html).

Comment: Thank you dyp. I put MyClass(MyClass&) to check this copy constructor is not called instead of MyClass(const MyClass&) although now I know both are not called in Func().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Func(mc);
> ```

This call will deduce `T` to be `MyClass&`. Note the reference. This is due to the way perfect forwarding has been introduced into C++: A *forwarding reference* such as the `T&&` function parameter of `Func` will be deduced to be an lvalue reference if the corresponding function argument is an lvalue-expression; otherwise (for xvalues and prvalues) it will not be deduced to be a reference type.

The type deduced for `T` will then be reference-collapsed with the `&&` from the function parameter `T&& t` to form the final function parameter type. In the case `Func(mc)`, `T == MyClass&`, so the function parameter becomes `MyClass& &&`, collapsed to `MyClass&`.

Since `T == MyClass&`, the declaration of the local variable `new_t_` will declare a *reference* in this case. No new object will be created:

```
template <>
void Func<MyClass&>(MyClass& t) {
    MyClass& new_t_(std::forward<MyClass&>(t));
    new_t_.val *= 2;
}
```

---

> ```
> Func(MyClass());
> ```

Here, the function argument is the prvalue-expression `MyClass()`. `T` will be deduced to `MyClass` (without reference). The function template instantiation produced looks like this:

```
template <>
void Func<MyClass>(MyClass&& t) {
    MyClass new_t_(std::forward<MyClass>(t));
    new_t_.val *= 2;
}
```

---

If you want to copy/move the function argument into a local variable, the `std::decay` metafunction can be used - or, more specific to the OP's problem, the `std::remove_reference` metafunction. E.g.

```
template <typename T>
void Func(T&& t) {
    using DT = typename std::decay<T>::type;
    DT new_t_(std::forward<T>(t));
    new_t_.val *= 2;
}
```